# Get Value and Count of that value using LINQ or lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

A list of data object in the below format

```
Col1  Col2  Col3

B     45    36    
B     12    69   
A     46    76    
C     89    09    
B     451   37   
D     435   46   
A     450   50   
D     98    43   
B     358   39
A     987   89
```

Need to get result set like following format ( 'A' occurred 3 times ,'B' occurred 4 times etc.)

```
Value  Count

A      3   
B      4  
C      1    
D      2
```

How to get result set like above using LINQ or lambda expressions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve it by lambda expression like

```
var list = from x in dataObjects
           group x by x.Col1 into g
           select new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

And By using Linq Extension method `GroupBy` as answered by @Asif

Answer (score 8):

You can use [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx) for that.

```
var groupedlist = list.GroupBy(c => c.Col1)
                      .Select((key, c) => new {Value = key, Count = c.Count()});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var dictionary = list.GroupBy(str => str.Col1)
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());
```

[from here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/a5f837bd-6405-4e88-a3de-b391c20b813a/)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look into using the [`.GroupBy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) LINQ method on `col1`. You can then use [`.Count()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038.aspx) on the resulting groups to determine how many are in each group.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<TestOverFlow> list = new List<TestOverFlow>() 
{
  new TestOverFlow {Col1="B",Col2=45,Col3=36},
  new TestOverFlow {Col1="B",Col2=12,Col3=69},
  new TestOverFlow {Col1="A",Col2=46,Col3=76},

  new TestOverFlow {Col1="C",Col2=89,Col3=09},
  new TestOverFlow {Col1="C",Col2=10,Col3=09},
  new TestOverFlow {Col1="C",Col2=89,Col3=1},
};

var Query = from result in list orderby result.Col1
            group result by result.Col1 into g 
            select new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };

foreach (var x in Query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", x.Value, x.Count);
}
```

Result:

```
Value Count     
A      1  
B      2  
C      3
```